# Yamm3 Navbar is collapsed at any resolution in IE8

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Yamm3 mega navbar which is built for bootstrap 3. It is working fine in all the browsers but IE8 the navbar is collpsed at any resolution.

I have included **respond.min.js** and **html5shiv.min.js** but it is not working, Please help me if you know th solution. Thanks.

The code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Demo navbar -->
    <div class="navbar yamm navbar-default navbar-fixed-top eziBuyTop">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Yamm Megamenu</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- Classic list -->
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">List<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <!-- Content container to add padding -->
                  <div class="yamm-content">
                    <div class="row">
                      <ul class="col-sm-2 list-unstyled">
                        <li>
                          <p><strong>Section Title</strong></p>
                        </li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="col-sm-2 list-unstyled">
                        <li>
                          <p><strong>Links Title</strong></p>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Link Item </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Link Item </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Link Item </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Link Item </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Link Item </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Link Item </a></li>
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="col-sm-2 list-unstyled">
                        <li>
                          <p><strong>Section Title</strong></p>
                        </li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="col-sm-2 list-unstyled">
                        <li>
                          <p><strong>Section Title</strong></p>
                        </li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>List Item</li>
                        <li>
                          <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"> Link Item </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Link Item </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Link Item </a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- Accordion demo -->
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Accordion<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <div class="yamm-content">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Collapsible Group Item #1</a></h4>
                          </div>
                          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">Ut consectetur ullamcorper purus a rutrum. Etiam dui nisi, hendrerit feugiat scelerisque et, cursus eu magna. </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Collapsible Group Item #2</a></h4>
                          </div>
                          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">Nullam pretium fermentum sapien ut convallis. Suspendisse vehicula, magna non tristique tincidunt, massa nisi luctus tellus, vel laoreet sem lectus ut nibh. </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Collapsible Group Item #3</a></h4>
                          </div>
                          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">Praesent leo quam, faucibus at facilisis id, rhoncus sit amet metus. Sed vitae ipsum non nibh mattis congue eget id augue. </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- Classic dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Classic<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Action </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Another action </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Something else here </a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Separated link </a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- Pictures -->
            <li class="dropdown yamm-fw"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Pictures<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <div class="yamm-content">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="http://placekitten.com/150/190/"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="http://placekitten.com/150/190/"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="http://placekitten.com/150/190/"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="http://placekitten.com/150/190/"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="http://placekitten.com/150/190/"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="http://placekitten.com/150/190/"></a></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="demo/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: let us see the nav bar's source or homepage link

Comment: Have you checked that you aren't running into one of Respond.js's several limitations/caveats?: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/README.md